# spring boot failed to start due to "The port may already be in use"

Tags: spring-boot

I tried to start my spring boot application on centos server with this command line.

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prd java -jar ./build/libs/port_switcher-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But I got an error message that the port is already in used.
then looked up process list which is used in the port number using netstat
but there is no process that uses the port number

and then I rerun my spring boot application without SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE variable. (it was an mistake that forget that variable)
at that time spring boot application run successfully.

I really want to know what problem is in my application properties

this command occur error

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prd java -jar ./build/libs/port_switcher-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

this command works fine

```
java -jar ./build/libs/port_switcher-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

application-prd.properties

```
#Server
server.address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
server.port=9090

#Devtools
spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=true
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true

# Logging
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.com.kakao.portswitcher=INFO
logging.path=logs

server.tomcat.basedir=./
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
#server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd
server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=access
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=logs
server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered=true

#Jackson
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE

# Status check file
status.file=./port_switcher_status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this :

`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prd ./build/libs/port_switcher-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: I just tried that command. but I got same error message. "The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigure"

Comment: `ps -ef | grep java | grep $user`

Check this and kill the java process if already exists

Comment: Does it work after killing the process and starting your spring-boot application?

Comment: Unfortunately, It does't work
There is no another process that uses same port.

I am wondering why it works without SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prd

Comment: I was my mistake. I wrote wrong ip for server.address in properties file. Thanks for relying